# image cannot upload to folder

Tags: php, image

i have a small problem i cannot figure out i need to upload an image to a folder called upload i successfully uploaded the name of the image to database table but for some reason the image is not being uploaded to folder here is my code

```js
<?PHP

session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (!(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] != '')) {
  header ("Location: log-in/login");
}

?>
<?php
include('configur.php');     

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    echo "Welcome '{$_SESSION['email']}'";
}      
?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php
echo"<a href = log-in/logout> Log out </a>";  
?><br> <br>
<?php
 require_once("configur.php");    

$query='UPDATE profile_table SET   images="'.$_FILES['file']['name'].'"
WHERE email= "'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';

if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
?>

<?php

include('configur.php');
 if($_POST)
 { 
 // $_FILES["file"]["error"] is HTTP File Upload variables $_FILES["file"] "file" is the name of input field you have in form tag.     

 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
 // if there is error in file uploading 
 echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";    

 }
 else
 {
 // check if file already exit in "images" folder.
 if (file_exists("upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
 {     
 }
 else
 {  //move_uploaded_file function will upload your image. 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
 {
 // If file has uploaded successfully, store its name in data base
 $query_image = "insert into profile_table";
  
 if(mysqli_query($link, $query_image))
 {
 echo "Stored in: " . "upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 }
 else
 {
 echo'';
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
<?PHP

session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (!(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] != '')) {

header ("Location: log-in/login");

}

?>
<?php
include('configur.php');
 

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    echo "Welcome '{$_SESSION['email']}'";
}

  
?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php
echo"<a href = log-in/logout> Log out </a>";  
?><br> <br>
<?php
 require_once("configur.php");
 

$query='UPDATE profile_table SET   images="'.$_FILES['file']['name'].'"
WHERE email= "'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';

if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
?>

<?php

include('configur.php');
 if($_POST)
 { 
 // $_FILES["file"]["error"] is HTTP File Upload variables $_FILES["file"] "file" is the name of input field you have in form tag.

 

 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
 // if there is error in file uploading 
 echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";

 

 }
 else
 {
 // check if file already exit in "images" folder.
 if (file_exists("upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
 {
 
 }
 else
 {  //move_uploaded_file function will upload your image. 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
 {
 // If file has uploaded successfully, store its name in data base
 $query_image = "insert into profile_table";
  
 if(mysqli_query($link, $query_image))
 {
 echo "Stored in: " . "upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 }
 else
 {
 echo'';
 }
 }
 }

 


 }
 }


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple example at:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp